# How to define a range using R for loop to create graphs

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, charts

I have a dataset in excel that looks like this:

```
MA  M1  M2  T1  T2  W1  W2  Th1 Th2  F1  F2
100 1   2   2   1   2   0   0   2   2   1
100 2   0   2   1   2   2   1   2   2   0
101 1   3   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   1
101 0   2   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1
102 1   1   1   2   0   1   0   0   2   2
102 1   2   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   3
```

I am trying to create a column chart for each code (100,101,102) where each code will have 2 data sets and the horizontal values will be m1, m2, t1, etc.
So in the end I want 3 column graphs. I am trying to use a for loop to create these graphs in VBA, and here is what I have been trying:

```
Sub MA()
   Dim i  As Integer
    Dim row1 As Integer, row2 As Integer
     For i = 1 To 6 Step 2
        Dim MAChart As Chart
        Set MAChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
         With MAChart
         row1 = i + 1
         row2 = i + 2
         .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
         .SetSourceData Source:=ActiveSheet.Range("Q& row1 & : & Z & row2")
         End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

I keep getting an "Application defined or object defined" error. I am having trouble defining the range of each chart since it changes based on i. I would love to find a clean way to make a series of charts using a for loop without redefining the range/dataset each time for each different chart. Does anyone know a good way to do this??

Comment: For one thing, dim your MAChart at the top, outside of the loop. It needs to be set for each loop, but only needs to be dimmed once. Beyond that, provide more info - on what line do you get the error? Without running through your code line by line, there could be several errors in it but it only gets to the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is treating the whole "range" as a string which would not equate to a range

```
Range("Q& row1 & : & Z & row2")
```

Try using below, you have no need for row1 and row2. Take note of how I am building up the string that makes a valid range

```
Range("Q" & 1+i & ":Z" & 2+i)
```

Used with your code be something like, notice I have also moved your "Dim" out of the loop this does not need to created each loop but needs to be "Set" every loop

```
Sub MA()
   Dim i  As Integer
   Dim MAChart As Chart
    Dim row1 As Integer, row2 As Integer
     For i = 1 To 6 Step 2
        Set MAChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
         With MAChart
         .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
         .SetSourceData Source:=ActiveSheet.Range("Q" & i & ":Z" & 1+i)
         End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

You may also want to consider the position of the charts above will create them all on top of each other.

Comment: Ok! thank you that seemed to fix the error - however, there is still a problem with the graphs. Instead of each graph having 2 series (for 100 they would be {1   2   2   1   2   0   0   2   2   1} and {2   0   2   1   2   2   1   2   2   0}) the graphs now have 10 series. It seems the data range is being read with each data series belonging to a column when I want each series to be the entire row so that there are only 2 series in each graph. Do you know a way to fix this?

Comment: I can not remember which way around these need to go but either you need .PlotBy = xlRows or .PlotBy = xlColumns just put one of these in the With MAChar, if one doesnt do it try the other, one of them should be the correct one